# Is there an evolutionary reason why people care so much about politics?

Tags: evolutionary-psychology

Is there an evolutionary reason why people care so much about politics? I speculate that it is because in ancestral times, politics was a literal life and death matter. Is there any books about this topic?

Comment: Although psychology may play a very small part in this question. I have a feeling this question is more a philosophical question in the realms of Plato et al. rather than a psychology question. If this question was based purely on the psychology of politics, it could lead to an answer which could fill a large book. Plus, if you look at https://politics.stackexchange.com the politics in a particular geographical region and social group can change quite often and rather quickly. What part of evolutionary psychology are you looking at with this question?

Comment: "in ancestral times, politics was a literal life and death matter" - is it not life and death today, too?

Comment: Evolutionary? From the top of my head, because humans have evolved to observe and appreciate cause and effect. Participating in politics exerts controls over causes, so that the desired effects may be obtained.

Comment: Are you talking about [tribalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribalism) ([ingroup/outgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-group_and_out-group)), or some other aspect of politics?